# Expect premature EOF when spawning forking process

Tags: openssl, tcl, expect, tty, ocsp

I have a rather long/complicated TCL/Expect script that runs an `openssl ocsp` responder in both CGI and Daemon modes. The script is complete and functional but I want to implement a multi-threaded OCSP daemon using `openssl ocsp -multi <#> ...` and it is showing some strange behavior.

- TCL 8.6.10
- Expect 5.45.4
- OpenSSL 1.1.1g 21 Apr 2020
- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 5.4.0-42-lowlatency x86_64

Here is the most succinct example code I could come up with (saved as `ocsp.tcl`):

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
#usage (run as root):
#./ocsp.tcl [multi] [sudo] [internal] [debug] [trace] [cmdtrace] [null] [raw] [rawinit] [forever]
package require Expect;                                     #make sure expect is loaded

if {[lsearch $::argv trace]!=-1} { strace 5 };              #arg - walk through expect script
if {[lsearch $::argv debug]!=-1} { exp_debug 1 };           #arg - prompt through expect script
if {[lsearch $::argv internal]!=-1} { exp_internal 1 };     #arg - show expect match logic
if {[lsearch $::argv null]!=-1} { remove_nulls 0 };         #arg - keep nulls in expect
if {[lsearch $::argv rawinit]!=-1} { set stty_init raw };   #arg - spawn with raw terminal
if {[lsearch $::argv forever]!=-1} { set timeout -1 };      #arg - expect doesn't time out

if {[lsearch $::argv sudo]!=-1} { lappend cmd sudo -n };    #arg - sudo before command
if {[lsearch $::argv cmdtrace]!=-1} { lappend cmd strace }; #arg - trace openssl execution
lappend cmd openssl ocsp -index index.txt -CA ca.crt;       #create command line
lappend cmd -rsigner ocsp.crt -rkey ocsp.key -nmin 300;     #create command line
lappend cmd -text -ignore_err -port 2650 -timeout 5;        #create command line
if {[lsearch $::argv multi]!=-1} { lappend cmd -multi 5 };  #arg - launch 5 child responders

puts "Command: $::argv0 $::argv";                           #debug - launch arguments
puts -nonewline "TCL: ${::tcl_patchLevel}\t";               #debug - TCL 8.6.10
puts -nonewline "Expect: [exp_version]\t";                  #debug - Expect 5.45.4
puts "OpenSSL: [exec -- openssl version]";                  #debug - OpenSSL 1.1.1g 21 Apr 2020
puts "OS: [exec -- lsb_release -ds] [exec -- uname -rm]";   #debug - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 5.4.0-42-lowlatency x86_64
puts -nonewline "remove_nulls: [remove_nulls]\t";           #debug - remove nulls
puts -nonewline "match_max: [match_max]\t";                 #debug - match_max
puts "parity: [parity]\tdebug: [exp_debug]";                #debug - parity, exp_debug
lappend ps ps -o pid=,ppid=,tt=,cmd= -C openssl;            #ps output syntax
#-----------------------------------------------------------
spawn {*}$cmd;                                              #run and show openssl command
#-----------------------------------------------------------
if {[lsearch $::argv raw]!=-1} { stty raw };                #arg - raw output to expect
puts -nonewline "spawn_id: ${spawn_id}\t";                  #debug - spawn_id
puts -nonewline "user_spawn_id: ${::user_spawn_id}\t";      #debug - user_spawn_id
puts -nonewline "error_spawn_id: ${::error_spawn_id}\t";    #debug - error_spawn_id
puts "tty_spawn_id: ${::tty_spawn_id}";                     #debug - tty_spawn_id
catch {puts "-----Spawn-----\n[exec -- {*}$ps]"};           #debug - openssl processes

expect {
  -re "Enter pass phrase for .*:" {
    catch {puts "\n-----Pre-Send-----\n[exec -- {*}$ps]"};  #debug - openssl processes
    exp_send "<password>\n";                              #input the key password
    catch {puts "-----Post-Send-----\n[exec -- {*}$ps]"};   #debug - openssl processes
    exp_continue;                                           #restart this expect loop
  }
  timeout { puts "Expect: Timeout"; exp_continue };         #debug - timeout
  full_buffer { puts "Expect: Full Buffer"; exp_continue }; #debug - full buffer
  #null { puts "Expect: Null"; exp_continue };              #debug - null (??SEGFAULTS??)
  eof { puts "Expect: We Should Never Get Here" };          #!!PROGRAM SHOULD NEVER REACH EOF!!
}

lassign [wait] pid spawnid os err;                          #get spawn exit details
puts -nonewline "pid: ${pid}\tspawn_id: ${spawnid}\t";      #show exit status
puts "os_error: ${os}\terror_num: ${err}";                  #show exit status
```

This script can be run with any options in any order like so: `./ocsp.tcl [multi] [sudo] [internal] [debug] [trace] [cmdtrace] [null] [raw] [rawinit] [forever]`

If everything goes correctly the script **shouldn't terminate**. Instead it should just end up repeating:

```
Expect: Timeout
Expect: Timeout
Expect: Timeout
```

Obviously some of the options will warp this output *(debug, internal, trace, cmdtrace)*, but with the same end result.

To summarize:

- The shell command **works**: `openssl ocsp -index index.txt -CA ca.crt -rsigner ocsp.crt -rkey ocsp.key -nmin 300 -text -ignore_err -port 2650 -timeout 5`
- The shell `multi` command **works**: `openssl ocsp -index index.txt -CA ca.crt -rsigner ocsp.crt -rkey ocsp.key -nmin 300 -text -ignore_err -port 2650 -timeout 5 -multi 5`
- Running both shell commands in the background (`&`) **works**
- Any of these options in any combination **works**: `./ocsp.tcl [sudo] [internal] [debug] [trace] [cmdtrace] [null] [raw] [rawinit] [forever]`
- Running `multi` with or without the other options **fails** before hitting `Expect: Timeout`: `./ocsp.tcl multi [internal] [debug] [trace] [cmdtrace] [null] [raw] [rawinit] [forever]`
- Running `multi` with `sudo` with or without the other options **works**: `./ocsp.tcl multi sudo [internal] [debug] [trace] [cmdtrace] [null] [raw] [rawinit] [forever]`

When the script **fails**, `tail -f /var/log/syslog` outputs `ocsp[<pid>]: fatal: error detaching from parent process group: Operation not permitted`. A look at [apps/lib/http_server.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/24b6261e5bb286fa494e7208a3de28365e0ca004/apps/lib/http_server.c) in the [OpenSSL source](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) shows that this is message is caused by a failed `setpgid`. [setpgid](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html) describes *Operation not permitted* as:

> EPERM - An attempt was made to move a process into a process group in a different session, or to change the process group ID of one of the children of the calling process and the child was in a different session, or to change the process group ID of a session leader (setpgid(), setpgrp()).

Where I am at:

- cooked/raw mode doesn't matter (`set stty_init [raw/cooked]; stty [-]raw`)
- This isnt a `tclsh` or `expect` issue, But it may be an *Expect* issue, specifically with `spawn`.
- It hopefully isn't an `openssl ocsp -multi <#> ..,` oddity/oversight/bug.
- **this has everything to do with how `spawn` creates/uses the pty/tty/session**
- `spawn -nottyinit -nottycopy` in any combination does nothing noticeable.

Right now I could just admit defeat and `spawn sudo ...` but it is *hackish*.

I'm currently *trying* to supplement/replace spawn with:

```
set pty_pid [spawn -noecho -pty]; #just create a pty? or do we make one for std[in|out|err]?
stty raw -echo < $spawn_out(slave,name); #don't echo stdin on the new pty?
#stty raw > $spawn_out(slave,name); #raw stdout on the new pty? THIS KILLS CTRL-C
set spawn_pid [exec -- {*}$cmd > $spawn_out(slave,name) < $spawn_out(slave,name) &] #redirect stin/out to the pty?
close -slave; #no idea
```

...but as you can tell by the snippet I'm not sure what specifically to do with these pty(s).

Any help getting `-multi` working would be greatly appreciated.

Edits:

- Cleaned everything up to reflect the real culprit (spawn/tty/pty/session/setpgid) as noticed by [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn)
- HEAVILY refactored the script for more debugging and added command outputs per [Donal Fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301832/donal-fellows) comments
- setting up a CA, root and OCSP signing certificates is outside of the scope of this post and a large endeavor in itself. [Jamie Linux - Online Certificate Status Protocol](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/online-certificate-status-protocol.html) covers it in sufficient detail. (to address [sexpect - Expect for Shells](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13534458/sexpect-expect-for-shells) comment)

Comment: could you paste a workable `index.txt` (and any other files which need to preexist) so i can give it a try?

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to build `cmd` with `lappend`. Perhaps printing the value of that immediately before the `spawn` (for debugging) would help you figure out what's wrong?

Comment: What error messages are printed when things don't work?

Comment: @DonalFellows - updated the script to reflect your concerns. There is no error message except the EOF message `puts "We Should Never Get Here"` in the `-multi` use case.

@sexpect-ExpectforShells -To setup a CA and OCSP responder is way too much code to paste here. Check out [Jamie Linux - Online Certificate Status Protocol](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/online-certificate-status-protocol.html) for a comprehensive guide.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. Have you tried turning on Expect's debug mode? It's possible that the output you're getting just doesn't quite match the REs you're using.

Comment: @DonalFellows - I have updated the post to address all of your comments. Noteably, `exp_internal 1` is very helpful (activated by `./ocsp.tcl internal [multi]`).

Comment: That error you're seeing in syslog is caused by a call to [`setpgid()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html) failing. There's something different about the process session and groups when expect spawns a process vs when strace or the shell does it.

Comment: @shawn- yes! I've been out but still looking into it. replacing strace with sudo also works. The problem is specifically the setpgid() error premission denied- EPERM. So The caller cannot change the PGID of the specified process: The specified process is a session leader, pid matches the PID of a child of the calling process, but the child is not in the same session as the caller, pgid does not match the PID of the process specified by pid, and it does not match the PGID of any other process in the caller's session. Will refactor the code and question to accommodate.

Comment: I think I may have encountered something similar, but in a completely different setup (OCSP responder / “server”). [So I’ve filed a bug here.](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/16205)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek mine is also an ocsp responder/server cgi/daemon :)